# background notification - blackberry

Tags: blackberry, mobile, java-me, notifications

I want to show the user notification even when the app is not open, using something like background notification. It will listen to a server and will retrieve updates every 30 minutes and show the user the message. How can I implement this on BlackBerry.

I don't want to use RIM push service.

Comment: How about you name your app "The battery killing monster app" ;-)

Comment: noooo, sorry, thats a requirement

Comment: Why not push? Is this app a BES app?

Comment: BES== Blackberry service. YES, Something like that

Comment: BES is blackberry enterprise server.

Comment: Rupak provides good advice. You can use two entry points, the normal UiApplication, and an Application that is set to auto start. However, rfsk2010 is also right. Polling is NOT the way to do things on BlackBerry. You won't be popular that way, especially with established users.

Comment: Using RIM's Push Service is not always a possibility, though.  It really depends on the source of the data that is being polled by, or pushed to, the device. Pushing requires both device-side and provider-side support, whereas polling is just device-side.

Answer (score 2):

Check the difference between [net.rim.device.api.system.Application](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Application.html) and [net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/UiApplication.html).

Applications which do not require any user interaction may be derived directly from `Application` class. Applications which require user interaction should be derived from `UiApplication`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate app (or give your existing app a second entry point) that implements `net.rim.device.api.system.Application` and is configured to run at device startup.  That instance of your app will then be running in its own background process for as long as the OS is running.  It can do whatever data polling it needs to do, and then display notifications to the user when needed, such as with the `net.rim.blackberry.api.messagelist.ApplicationIndicator` and `net.rim.blackberry.api.messagelist.ApplicationMessageFolder` APIs, or your own custom UI.